# Can i create a tennis game with unreal engine?

Tags: unreal-engine4

The question is above...im newbie with `unreal engine` and just want to start a hobby...so i'd like to spend my time with gameccreation. How can i do sports game like tennis with unreal? what can i do or could someone write links or just explain how it works? Or i just try with different engine? I tried download ffrom the webpage and istalled it...but i dont know. And i have to write c++ or i can use other program language? Blueprint what is it in this engine? And if i want like a tennis game what can  i choose? SSo all in all it would be useful if someone explain how it works the whole thing.    Thank u very much!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

You can make any game in the Unreal Engine. I highly recommend you check out https://wiki.unrealengine.com/Videos for some video tutorials on UE4 to get started. You do not have to touch any C++ when you use Blueprint, but it is highly recommended to learn some C++ eventually so that you can add your own functionality to make the engine do more than it was originally intended.

That said, designing a game even with a game engine is an incredibly difficult endeavor. Especially for people who are new to the whole scene. Just make sure to watch a lot of video tutorials if you are a visual learner or read lots of documentation on how to do different things. Don't expect to make any huge projects, such as large open world MMOs. Try to make really small, simple projects. You can use those to learn different aspects of game development and eventually be able to work your way up to larger and larger projects.